# Qt4 and DNS records

Tags: qt, qt4, dns, cname

Does Qt 4 support resolving DNS records such as CNAME, MX and SRV?

There's a Q3Dns class, but I'd prefer not to use it.

Comment: It seems I managed to cut the rest of my post somehow. I wanted to say that there's the Q3Dns class, but I'd prefer not to use it.

Comment: You should edit your post instead of adding this comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm a little new around here. Well, I went with Q3Dns. Better options are still welcome tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/q3dns.html

Should have all the information you need.

Edit: As far as I can see there is no low-level version except for the one above.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/porting4.html#qdns

You could code something yourself from scratch like this [MFC based example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dns_application.aspx) which shouldn't be too hard to port.

Comment: Oh, the rest of my question got snipped. My bad. Anyway, I wanted to say I'd like to stay away from Qt 3.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm a little new around here. Well, I went with Q3Dns. Better options are still welcome tho.